# iis-express file access permissions

Tags: wcf, iis-express

I'm running a wcf service hosted on iis express 7.5.
Inside the service, i have a service operation that needs to write a file on the filesystem, but when it tries to do so, i'm getting an exception.

i'm writing the file to the exact same folder where the project is hosted, by using:
string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".");

but i keep getting this exception:

DirectoryNotFoundException - "Could not find a part of the path C:\websites....

It seems like my iis express doesn't have permission to write files.
if so, how do i give it permission?

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. IIS Express runs under current logged on user identity. If the folder you are trying to write has some special access, then provide acccess to current user.
2. File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create) would create only files, if the directory does not exit, it throws 'DirectoryNotFound' exception and it is expected. So, before creating a file, make sure that directory exists. probably you can use Directory.CreateDirectory("directory path") API

Comment: Thank you! the problem was solved when I've created the directory first, and only then created the file. I thought File.Open should do this all together, but i was indeed wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You need to grant write permissions to the NETWORK SERVICE account to the folder you are trying to write. Also the MapPath method takes a relative url to the root of the virtual directory:

```
var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'll just mention that the file i'm trying to create is supposed to be created in a folder which still doesn't exist, so I'm using  FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create); i gave all the permissions to Network Service and added it up until my c:\ folder, but still i get the same exception: "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\websites\myproject\project.Web\newfolder\21Icon.jpg'."

Comment: When I try to write file, I am getting access denied error even with NETWORK SERVICE write permission to the folder :/